# Want more details about the image of a Maass form in the AIM press release concerning LMFDB

Tags: nt.number-theory, reference-request, maass-forms

Actually I came upon this through MO a couple of days ago: in here
(http://aimath.org/aimnews/lmfdb/) there is a mesmerizing image

[image]

The caption reads

> A Maass form, one of the 20 different types of objects in the LMFDB.
>
> Image by Fredrik Strömberg

Of course I could just email [the person](https://www.nottingham.ac.uk/mathematics/people/fredrik.stromberg) or [Alina Bucur](http://www.math.ucsd.edu/%7Ealina/gallery/) whose homepage hosts the image, or ask at [LMFDB](http://www.lmfdb.org/) but I somehow prefer to start from here.

Does anyone know which Maass form is depicted here? What does the color coding mean? How has it been calculated? Where can I read about it?

After accepting an answer I found (in the "Related" column), in [an answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/34515/41291) to [Zeroes of Maass forms](https://mathoverflow.net/q/34500/41291) a link to a [more informative page](http://www.mathematik.tu-darmstadt.de/fbereiche/AlgGeoFA/staff/stroemberg/research/gallery/) by Strömberg with lots of different kind of images like

[image]

or

[image]

Then I also found another even more haunting and mysterious one at [still different page](http://www.mathematik.tu-darmstadt.de/fbereiche/AlgGeoFA/staff/stroemberg/), again without any details given. Let me reproduce this one too

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find details on the Maass waveform calculation in SAGE in this [talk](http://math.uni.lu/~wiese/CMF/resources/StroembergPoster.pdf) by Frederik Strömberg. I guess you'll have to ask [Dr. Strömberg](https://sites.google.com/site/fredrikstroemberg/home/research) for the precise parameters used in the waveform you mention.

Comment: OK seems like I have to ask him in any case. But I am very grateful for the link of the talk, I don't think I would be able to discover it myself.